# Create UIButton the width of its title

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uibutton

I'm trying to make a `UIButton` the same width as its title by doing this:

```
CGSize stringSize = [[tagArray lastObject] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"System 14.0"}];
tagButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, stringSize.width, 30);
```

However it's crashing on the `CGSize` line. Any pointers? The object in the array is just a regular `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to:

```
CGSize stringSize = [[tagArray lastObject] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]}];
```